# Correct way of handling multiple TCP sockets in single thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, tcp, poco-libraries

I don't have any code to provide, just need an advice.

I am using Poco::Net as network library in my project.
The task I am trying to resolve: I have up to 4 client connections in single 'game session'.
I need:
- Read from any of them if data is available.
- Send data via multicast.
- Possibly use 1 thread for accepting connections, and 1 thread for interaction with them.
- If TCP connection was broken, I need to store data that should be sent to this client, and when he reconnects back (new TCP Socket is created, and I identify clients by they unique key that they send in first packet), and re-sent everything I stored during they internet connection issues.

I have read about Poco::Net::SocketReactor/Poco::Net::SocketAcceptor combination, but its unclear to me how can I get access to Handlers from outside them, since Reactor does not provide an API to get them (I want to integrate packets validation on receive, not at processing stage). Also, since Handler is created for every new connection, I can't place "re-sent on disconnect" logic inside Handler, it should be placed outside.

So, it looks to me that I can't use Reactor/Acceptor pattern, and have to deal with raw StreamSocket's. But how to do it in single thread, without busy-loop?

Also, if you know how to do it correctly using other libraries (boost::asio for e.g.), please recommend something.

Comment: the boost asio documentation has a number of example programs demonstrating this.

Comment: Actually not placing  "re-sent on disconnect" logic inside Handler is a good idea.

Comment: Not familiar with Poco library, but most designs use [`select`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) to let a thread get informed that a socket is ready to read/write without blocking. Or a similar function depending on platform, socket count and the needs for the the thread to do other things (e.g. files as well, or UI, etc.) such as the Win32 [`GetQueuedCompletionStatus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364986(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks @FireLancer , my bad, I did not read select() documentation properly - thanks actually what I need.

Comment: @FireLancer - `select` is a good starting point and a good advice, however, `select` is a very old approach that's mostly used for portability. `select` has many issues on different systems and performance oriented solutions usually use the system specific alternative (`epoll` on Linux, `kqueue` on macOS/BSD, etc').

Comment: yes, but afaik `select` is the only common one good enough for basics without going for some extra library or another, but yes it fall short in many cases, especially on Windows.